# .NET implementation of MongoDB remove command

Tags: c#, mongodb

From the console this is as easy as running the command:

```
db.<collectionName>.remove();
```

This does not appear to be implemented as part of the .NET driver functionality. How can I produce similar functionality within a .NET\C# program? I have a staging collection that I want to remove all records from after processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RemoveAll` to remove all records from a collection:

```
db.GetCollection("test").RemoveAll();
```

Comment: Wow, that easy. I now feel bad about myself for not being able to figure that out, but thank you very much for the help. Is this something you knew already or am I not as good at Google searching for the documentation as I thought I was?

Comment: @TechDawg270 I just used Intellisense on the collection object; figured it probably started with 'remove' and there it was.